# ExtJS let second form.TextArea grow when the first form.TextArea grows

Tags: javascript, extjs

I created an Ext Application, which does not run. But that's not the point of this question.
My question is: for given two textAreas I'd like to grow the second one when the first grows

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.TextArea', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        grow: true,
        id: 'm1',
    });


Ext.create('Ext.form.TextArea', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        grow: true,
        id: 'm2',
    });
},
});
```

I was thinking about:

```
bind: {
height: '{m1.height}',
}
```

But when trying, that didn't work.

Then I was thinking about:

```
 var el = Ext.get("m1");
 var e2 = Ext.get("m2");
 e2.setHeight(e1.getHeight());
```

Then a friend of mine proposed to use the `resize` event listener.

Any idea how to change the bind to get it work?

Link to the fiddle with the code above:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3k6s

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this on modern (`grow` is only for classic) --but I can be wrong. Are you developing on modern or classic?

Comment: I'm developing on classic. And I think I have found the problem. 
The problem seems to be that after resizing one element, the 'resize' event is being fired again. And then again and again. It didn't even help to use `suspendEvents(false)` and `resumeEvents(true)` methods.

Comment: An alternative is to add a listener to "m1" (and better use a `reference` or `itemId` rather than an `id`) to the `change` event: then you can `getHeight()` and `setHeight()`.

Comment: Arthur, do you have any idea how to refer to the `m2` element by reference from within the `m1` element?

Comment: Something like: `{xtype: 'textfield', reference: 'm1', bind: {value: 'Hi {m2.value}'}}, {xtype: 'textfield', reference: 'm2', publishes: 'value'}`. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I wished I had something like this but working (the example below is not working)
   ``` items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Teste',
        reference: 'text1',
        publishes: 'height',
        height: '100px',
    },{
        reference: 'text2',
        publishes: 'value',
        bind: {
            height: '{text1.height}',
        }```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
title: 'Sample TextArea',
width: 400,
bodyPadding: 10,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    grow: true,
    name: 'message',
    fieldLabel: 'Message',
    anchor: '100%',
    grow: true,
    listeners: {
        resize: function(textArea, width, height) {
            textArea.nextSibling().setHeight(height)
        }
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    grow: true,
    name: 'message',
    fieldLabel: 'Message',
    anchor: '100%',
    grow: true,
}]
```

});

Comment: Arthur, yes - something like this, but my final goal is to have it working in two directions (so the first field height also changes when the second field's height changes).
I made a workaround and packed the two elements in the hbox and now the height of both of them changes automatically when one's height changes.

Comment: Could you have a look at this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3kbc
?
I'm wondering why the textarea of the second field is not growing, but the element within the green border does actually.